# CSV file to redshift using talend

Tags: postgresql, csv, talend, amazon-redshift

Windows 8.1 
talend version:5.6

JOb design:

tFileinputDelimited >> tredshiftoutput

I am loading 1 millon data from csv file to redshift. After loading of 5 lakshs data I am getting these errors:

Exception in component tRedshiftOutput_1
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: /rds/bin/padb.1.0.867/data/exec/58/0: failed to map segment from shared object: Cannot allocate memory
  Detail:

---

error:  /rds/bin/padb.1.0.867/data/exec/58/0: failed to map segment from shared object: Cannot allocate memory
  code:      1015
  context:   dlopen(/rds/bin/padb.1.0.867/data/exec/58/0,RTLD_LAZY)
  query:     4234372
  location:  exec_plan.cpp:2213
  process:   padbmaster [pid=15630]

---

```
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2096)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1829)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:510)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:386)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:332)
at project_1.red_mysqltest_0_1.red_mysqltest.tFileInputDelimited_1Process(red_mysqltest.java:1056)
at project_1.red_mysqltest_0_1.red_mysqltest.runJobInTOS(red_mysqltest.java:1802)
at project_1.red_mysqltest_0_1.red_mysqltest.main(red_mysqltest.java:1646)
```

[statistics] disconnected

How to resolve these errors??

Comment: for redshift bulk load from csv - please use COPY tablename FROM command. use tRedshiftRow to execute the command do not use tredshiftoutput component as its not advisable for bulk loads.

Comment: Can you please explain me how to do that???

Comment: i would suggest you can search on internet about how to load data into redshift from csv and that will lead you to copy from command syntax. and you have to use the same command in tRedshiftRow component of talend..before doing that you have to upload your csv to aws S3 bucket

Answer (score 0):

To use COPY command you need to copy all the csv file in S3.

To copy files in S3 you can use tSystem component with below command -

```
 "aws s3 cp /home/filename.csv  s3://data/"
```

then you can use tRedshiftRow to use COPY command which copy the data from S3 to table. If you are not using S3 then just direct pass path of the file.

```
 "COPY tablename
  FROM 's3://location/filename.csv'
  credentials 
          'aws_access_key_id= enter_access_key;
           aws_secret_access_key=enter_aws_secret_access_ket' 

          CSV DELIMITER ';' IGNOREHEADER 1  BLANKSASNULL EMPTYASNULL MAXERROR 10;"
```

For more detail see this  [COPY](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/tutorial-loading-run-copy.html)

Comment: I dont know any other way ,speed also depend on yours internet bandwidth